# JHipster UAA - Your request cannot be processed

Tags: jhipster

I just start to play with JHipster 4.11.0 and using ubuntu 17.10.
I generated an application using UAA server option. It seems that everything was generated with no problem.
After the generation have succeeded I started the app with ./mvnw command.
I'm using postgresql as database and liquibase have created the tables as expected. The message I have received at console is:

```
Application 'uaa' is running! Access URLs:
Local:      http://localhost:9876
External:   http://127.0.1.1:9876
Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
```

But I'm receiving an error at browser:

```
Your request cannot be processed
```

At chrome console I'm seeing this:

> fixurl.js:148 A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://linkhelp.clients.google.com/tbproxy/lh/wm?sourceid=wm&url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2F&hl=en&site=localhost%3A9876&error=http404&js=true, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.
>   ib @ fixurl.js:148

What am I missing here?

---

I tried to create a monolith application and it worked. so, the problem is related to UAA application.

Comment: It is the name of the generated JHipster UAA, since generator didn't let me use jhipster-uaa.

Comment: OK, I was just checking you did not choose a conflicting name for your app.